# RESTful Job Assignment

Tags: rest

I have a collection of jobs that need processing, http://example.com/jobs. Each job has a status of "new", "assigned" or "finished".

I want slave processes to pick off one "new" job, set it's status to "assigned", and then process it. I want to ensure each job is only processed by a single slave.

I considered having each slave do the following:

1. GET http://example.com/jobs
2. Pick one that's "new" and do an http PUT to http://example.com/jobs/123 {"status=assigned"}.
3. Repeat

The problem is that another slave may have assigned the job to itself between the GET and PUT. I could have the second PUT return a 409 (conflict), which would signal the second slave to try a different job.

Am I on the right track, or should I do this differently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was a little to specific, I don't actually care that the slave gets to pick the job, just that it gets a unique one.

With that in mind, I think @manuel aldana was on the right track, but I've made a few modifications.

I'll keep the /jobs resource, but also expose a /jobs/assigned resource. A single job may exist in both collections.

The slave can POST to /jobs/assigned with no parameters. The server will choose one "new" job, move it to "assigned", and return the url (/jobs/assigned/{jobid} or /jobs/{jobid}) in the Location header with a 201 status.

When the slave finishes the job, it will PUT to /jobs/{jobid} (status=finished).

Answer (score 1):

I would have one process that picks "new" jobs and assigns them.  Other processes would independently go in and look to see if they've been assigned a job.  You'd have to have some way to identify which process a job is assigned to, so some kind of slave process id would be called for.

Comment: This adds complexity, it forces me to keep track of slaves.

Answer (score 0):

(You could use POST too, as what you're trying to do shouldn't be idempotent anyway).

You could give each of your clients a unique ID (possibly a UUID) and have an "assignee/worker" field in your job resource.

1. GET http://example.com/jobs/
2. POST { "worker"=$myID } to http://example.com/jobs/123
3. GET http://example.com/jobs/123 and check that the worker ID is that of the client

You could combine this with conditional requests too.

On top of this, you could have a time out feature if the job queue doesn't hear back from a given client, it puts it back in the queue.

Answer (score 0):

It looks that the statuses are an essential part of your job-domain model. So I would expose this as dedicated sub-resources

```
# 'idle' is what you called 'new'
GET /jobs/idle
GET /jobs/assigned

# start job
PUT /jobs/assigned/123
```

Slave is only allowed to gather jobs by `GET /jobs/idle`. This never includes jobs which are running. Still there could be race conditions (two slaves are getting the set, before one them has started job). I think 400 Bad Request or your mentioned 409 Conflict are alright with that.

I prefer above resource-structure instead of working with payloads (which often looks more "procedural" to me).

Comment: 400 Bad Requests is for requests that are not understood (badly formatted, etc.), not for conflicts/unavailability. In addition, if you want a RESTful system, do make use of the payload: http://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2008/rest-apis-must-be-hypertext-driven

Comment: yeah you're right, 409 maybe is more expressive. regarding payload: i don't say that you shouldn't make use of payloads (of course each job should have a representation by payload including its status information). but I don't like to use 'action-payloads' (which would be the case if I send a trigger-payload to start a job).